# Do you add new HP or change ability score first when leveling up (eg, to 4th, 8th)?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, hit-points

When leveling up to 4th level, I add 2 ability points to CON, e.g., going from 14 (+2) to 16 (+3). For my new max HP, do I use my new CON modifier, or the old one?

Comment: If this question doesn't answer your query, please let us know what's missing/different and we can reopen.

Comment: Yay! And don't worry about being a duplicate. It's a good thing to have different ways of asking the same thing as it helps other who may ask it like that.